slow vtk rendering on ec2 machine
I am running the following code to render a 3D mesh using vtk.
On my MacBook Pro M2 (32GB RAM), the code runs significantly faster compared to AWS EC2 instances, including both CPU (c7i.8xlarge) and GPU (g5.2xlarge).
Specifically, the call to window_to_image_filter.Update() is about 100x slower on the cloud machines. I suspect this is something to do with laking of screen.
Class MyRenderer:
def __init__(self, mesh: trimesh.Trimesh):
    self.vtkmesh = create_vtk_mesh(mesh.vertices, mesh.faces) # This returns vtkPolyData mesh
    self.renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    self.render_window = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    self.render_window.AddRenderer(self.renderer)
    self.render_window.SetOffScreenRendering(False)
    self.render_window.SetSize(128, 128)

    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputData(self.vtkmesh)
    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)
    self.renderer.AddActor(actor)
    self.camera = vtk.vtkCamera()
    self.camera.ParallelProjectionOn()
    self.camera.SetParallelScale(75)
    self.camera.SetClippingRange(1, 400)
    self.renderer.SetActiveCamera(self.camera)
    self.render_window.Render()

def render_mesh(self, camera_position: np.ndarray, camera_focal_point: np.ndarray, pts_3d=None):
    self.camera.SetPosition(*camera_position)
    self.camera.SetFocalPoint(*camera_focal_point)
    view_matrix = self.camera.GetViewTransformMatrix()
    projection_matrix = self.camera.GetProjectionTransformMatrix(1, -1, 1)
    view_matrix_np = np.array([view_matrix.GetElement(i, j) for i in range(4) for j in range(4)]).reshape((4, 4))
    projection_matrix_np = np.array([projection_matrix.GetElement(i, j) for i in range(4) for j in range(4)]).reshape((4, 4))
    rotation_det = np.linalg.det(view_matrix_np[:3, :3])
    imaging_matrix = projection_matrix_np @ view_matrix_np

    sensor_normal = camera_focal_point - camera_position
    sensor_normal = sensor_normal / np.linalg.norm(sensor_normal)
    sensor_plane = sensor_normal[0], sensor_normal[1], sensor_normal[2], -np.dot(camera_position, sensor_normal)

    self.renderer.SetActiveCamera(self.camera)
    self.render_window.Render()

    window_to_image_filter = vtk.vtkWindowToImageFilter()
    window_to_image_filter.SetInput(self.render_window)
    
    # Bencmark:
    # On Apple MAC M2 - 0.001
    # AWS EC2 c7i.8xlarge Amazon linux (cpu) - 0.130
    # AWS EC2 g5.2xlarge Ubuntu (GPU) - 0.134
    with timing('this is slow'):
        window_to_image_filter.Update()

Here are the benchmark results for the line window_to_image_filter.Update():

Mac M2: ~0.001 seconds
AWS EC2 c7i.8xlarge (CPU): ~0.130 seconds AWS
EC2 g5.2xlarge (GPU): ~0.134 seconds

What I've Tried

Running the code with xvfb for virtual display on EC2 (must).
Switching from vtk-9.4.0 to vtk-osmesa, but the performance remains the same.

I suspect the issue might be related to the lack of a physical screen or hardware-specific optimizations. Is there any way to make the rendering on EC2 as fast as on my Mac, or at least 10x faster?
Since I call render_mesh() on ~500 different camera_position in my flow, it important for me to speed it up.
How can I optimize the rendering pipeline on AWS EC2 to reduce the time for window_to_image_filter.Update()?
Are there specific configurations or hardware requirements that could resolve this performance discrepancy?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
